# error in ajax and json array

Tags: ajax, arrays, json, parsing

I'm going to develop an interactive map (google maps).The coordinates parse via ajax from json,but i get error

JSON Format

```
{"Level":[{"route":[{"lat":39.105251,"lgn":26.551727},
{"lat":39.105247125,"lgn":26.551774625}...],"balls":
[{"lat":39.105239375,"lgn":26.551869875},{"lat":39.10524325,"lgn":26.55182225}]},
{"route":[{........},{.....}...],"balls":[{........},{.....}...]}]}
```

AJAX REQUEST

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "getcoordp?q=2",
   dataType: "json",
   cache: false,
   contentType: "application/json",
   success: function(data) {
  $.each(data.Level, function(i,Level){
    $.each(data.route, function(index, route) {
        alert(data.lat)
        });  
    }); 

   }
   });
```

ERROR

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace below

```
$.each(data.route, function(index, route)...
```

With

```
$.each(Level.route, function(index, route) {
    alert(route.lat)
});
```

This will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for(i=0;i<data.Level.length;i++){
console.log(data.Level[i].route);
}
```